# CSV PARSING THROUGH PYTHON

Tags: csv

I have a sample csv file . I have to parse only ip address , port and qid related columns from the csv file. and store it in json format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWKj5.png)

Please help.

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question and to share the results of it in the question.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? As written, this is a "write this code for me" question, which is not how to write a question here. Plus it doesn't help to put your title in all-caps like you're shouting for others to help. Please edit your question accordingly, before it ends up being closed as off-topic.

Comment: read the csv in pandas and filter the columns to keep only what you need. Try finding a beginner tutorial like this one: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv.html

Comment: Also - you should include a snippet of your file, *not* a screencap. And the screencap you *did* include is not a valid csv file, considering all the preamble content before the actual data.

Comment: I am able to parse the output that gives me all the output but i need selected values. i used csv module. I am new to python

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
with open(your csv file)as _file:
   ip_addresses = [ line.split()[0] for line in file.readlines() ]
```

assuming ip address as first column, hence 0 index, also it seems as if your csv requires cleaning up, also csvs are just text files seperated by commas

Comment: The OP said they already know how to parse csv. They haven't shared any code, so we have no idea *how* they are parsing it. So your answer isn't really solving any known problem (because, again, they haven't shared a single detail about their code).